# conflicting types and no return

Tags: c

Hello I am doing a program of the kind of a quiz but it is giving me two error one and in "error: conflicting types for 'Pergunta2'" and the other error is in Return I want the user to choose between "M" and "F" but in the structure store "masculino" or "feminino" but isn’t someone doing it who can help me? Thank you.

```
int main()
{

    questionario();
}

void questionario()
{

    int numero = 0;

    struct pessoas{
        int numero_questionario, idade;
        char sexo;
    }QUESTIONARIO[MAXQUESTIONARIO];

    QUESTIONARIO[0].numero_questionario = numero++;

    QUESTIONARIO[0].idade = pergunta1();
    QUESTIONARIO[0].sexo = pergunta2();

    printf("\nnunmero do questionario:%d, idade:%d, sexo:%c ", QUESTIONARIO[0].numero_questionario, QUESTIONARIO[0].idade, QUESTIONARIO[0].sexo);

}

int pergunta1()
{
    int resposta;

    printf("\nPergunta 1 - Idade do participante?");
    printf("\nResposta - ");
    scanf("%d", &resposta);
    if(resposta < 18)
    {
        do{

        printf("\nTem que ser maior de idade.");
        printf("\nResposta - ");
        scanf("%d", &resposta);
        }while(resposta < 18);
    }
    return resposta;
}

char pergunta2()
{
    char resposta;
        printf("\nPergunta 2 - Genero");
        printf("\n   (M)asculino");
        printf("\n   (F)eminino");
    do{
        printf("\nResposta - ");
        scanf("%s", &resposta);
    }while(resposta !='M' && resposta !='m' && resposta !='F' && resposta !='f');
    
    if(resposta == 'M' || resposta == 'm')
    {
        resposta = 'masculino';
    }else if(resposta == 'F' || resposta == 'f')
    {
        resposta = 'femenino';
    }

    return resposta;
}
```

Comment: Use a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your program. Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Consider using the [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/)

Comment: `scanf("%s", &resposta);` - but `resposta` is only one character. It is trying to read a string that takes at least two characters (one for the null at the end!). Perhaps `scanf("%c", &resposta)` would be better

Comment: Also look up `tolower`

Comment: And add `-Werror` to the switches if you want to be extra pedantic...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't declare a function before it's used, the compiler will make an "implicit declaration" that the function takes no arguments and returns an `int`. Then your explicit declaration of `void questionario()` conflicts with the implicit declaration `int questionario()`.

```
int main()
{   
    // implicit declaration `int questionario()`.
    questionario();
}

// conflicting explicit declaration for `questionario`
void questionario()
{
    ...
}
```

You can fix this by reordering the function declarations so they are declared before they are used.

```
void questionario()
{
    ...
}

int main()
{
    questionario();
}
```

Sometimes this is not possible. Then use a [forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) which repeats the function signature. Remember to change both.

```
void questionario();

int main()
{
    questionario();
}

void questionario()
{
    ...
}
```